# Pyramid web framework hello world not working

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to run the ["hello world" application](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/firstapp.html) for the Pyramid web framework but getting the following error. Can someone please tell me what I need to install. Thanks

```
C:\Python27>python pyramid_hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyramid_hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\config\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pyramid.interfaces import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\interfaces.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zope.deprecation import deprecated
ImportError: No module named deprecation

C:\Python27>pip install zope
Downloading/unpacking zope
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement zope
No distributions at all found for zope
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Tracy\pip\pip.log

C:\Python27>pip install zope.deprecation
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.deprecation in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zope.deprecation-4.1.1-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.26-py2.7.egg (from zope.deprecation)
Cleaning up...

C:\Python27>pip install zope.deprecation --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: zope.deprecation in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zope.deprecation-4.1.1-py2.7.egg
Downloading/unpacking distribute from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.7.3.zip#md5=c6c59594a7b180af57af8a0cc0cf5b4a (from zope.deprecation)
  Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145kB): 145kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package distribute

Downloading/unpacking setuptools>=0.7 (from distribute->zope.deprecation)
  Downloading setuptools-3.4.4.tar.gz (794kB): 794kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package setuptools

Installing collected packages: distribute, setuptools
  Found existing installation: distribute 0.6.26
    Uninstalling distribute:
      Successfully uninstalled distribute
  Running setup.py install for distribute

  Found existing installation: distribute 0.6.26
    Can't uninstall 'distribute'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Running setup.py install for setuptools

    Installing easy_install-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing easy_install.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing easy_install.exe.manifest script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing easy_install-2.7-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing easy_install-2.7.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
    Installing easy_install-2.7.exe.manifest script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Successfully installed distribute setuptools
Cleaning up...

C:\Python27>python pyramid_hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyramid_hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\config\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pyramid.interfaces import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\interfaces.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zope.deprecation import deprecated
ImportError: No module named deprecation

C:\Python27>pip install deprecation
Downloading/unpacking deprecation
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement deprecation
No distributions at all found for deprecation
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Tracy\pip\pip.log
```

Using virtualenv:

```
C:\Python27>easy_install virtualenv
Searching for virtualenv
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Best match: virtualenv 1.11.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.11.4.tar.gz#md5=9accc2d3f0ec1da479ce2c3d1fdff06e
Processing virtualenv-1.11.4.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-o3mttl\virtualenv-1.11.4\setup.cfg
Running virtualenv-1.11.4\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-o3mttl\virtualenv-1.11.4\egg-dist-tmp-qi3l26
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\_templates'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\_build'
Adding virtualenv 1.11.4 to easy-install.pth file
Installing virtualenv-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing virtualenv.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing virtualenv.exe.manifest script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing virtualenv-2.7-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing virtualenv-2.7.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing virtualenv-2.7.exe.manifest script to C:\Python27\Scripts

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.11.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for virtualenv
Finished processing dependencies for virtualenv

C:\Python27>set VENV=c:\env

C:\Python27>c:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv %VENV%
New python executable in c:\env\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

C:\Python27>cd\

C:\>cd env

C:\env>%VENV%\Scripts\easy_install "pyramid==1.5"
Searching for pyramid==1.5
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyramid/
Best match: pyramid 1.5
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyramid/pyramid-1.5.tar.gz#md5=8747658dcbab709a9c491e43d3b0d58b
Processing pyramid-1.5.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-_ci7js\pyramid-1.5\setup.cfg
Running pyramid-1.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-_ci7js\pyramid-1.5\egg-dist-tmp-3di1fa
Adding pyramid 1.5 to easy-install.pth file
Installing ptweens-script.py script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing ptweens.exe script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing ptweens.exe.manifest script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pdistreport-script.py script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pdistreport.exe script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pdistreport.exe.manifest script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing proutes-script.py script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing proutes.exe script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing proutes.exe.manifest script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pshell-script.py script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pshell.exe script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pshell.exe.manifest script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing prequest-script.py script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing prequest.exe script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing prequest.exe.manifest script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pviews-script.py script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pviews.exe script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pviews.exe.manifest script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pcreate-script.py script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pcreate.exe script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pcreate.exe.manifest script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pserve-script.py script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pserve.exe script to c:\env\Scripts
Installing pserve.exe.manifest script to c:\env\Scripts

Installed c:\env\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyramid==1.5
Searching for PasteDeploy>=1.5.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/PasteDeploy/
Best match: PasteDeploy 1.5.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PasteDeploy/PasteDeploy-1.5.2.tar.gz#md5=352b7205c78c8de4987578d19431af3b
Processing PasteDeploy-1.5.2.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cfzau8\PasteDeploy-1.5.2\setup.cfg
Running PasteDeploy-1.5.2\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-cfzau8\PasteDeploy-1.5.2\egg-dist-tmp-f7vrej
Adding pastedeploy 1.5.2 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\env\lib\site-packages\pastedeploy-1.5.2-py2.7.egg
Searching for translationstring>=0.4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/translationstring/
Best match: translationstring 1.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/translationstring/translationstring-1.1.tar.gz#md5=0979b46d8f0f852810c8ec4be5c26cf2
Processing translationstring-1.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ekrgr1\translationstring-1.1\setup.cfg
Running translationstring-1.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ekrgr1\translationstring-1.1\egg-dist-tmp-o3xqh2
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
Adding translationstring 1.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\env\lib\site-packages\translationstring-1.1-py2.7.egg
Searching for venusian>=1.0a3
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/venusian/
Best match: venusian 1.0a8
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/venusian/venusian-1.0a8.tar.gz#md5=a1a72166fd7cccf0f30e3305e09ce5cf
Processing venusian-1.0a8.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-otkbse\venusian-1.0a8\setup.cfg
Running venusian-1.0a8\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-otkbse\venusian-1.0a8\egg-dist-tmp-wxnee2
Adding venusian 1.0a8 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\env\lib\site-packages\venusian-1.0a8-py2.7.egg
Searching for zope.deprecation>=3.5.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/zope.deprecation/
Best match: zope.deprecation 4.1.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zope.deprecation/zope.deprecation-4.1.1.tar.gz#md5=ce261b9384066f7e13b63525778430cb
Processing zope.deprecation-4.1.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-vv7_t0\zope.deprecation-4.1.1\setup.cfg
Running zope.deprecation-4.1.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-vv7_t0\zope.deprecation-4.1.1\egg-dist-tmp-g86gig
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Adding zope.deprecation 4.1.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\env\lib\site-packages\zope.deprecation-4.1.1-py2.7.egg
Searching for zope.interface>=3.8.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/zope.interface/
Best match: zope.interface 4.1.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/z/zope.interface/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg#md5=97fc757b020bb25b829f9c566d87c8c3
Processing zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg
creating c:\env\lib\site-packages\zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg
Extracting zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg to c:\env\lib\site-packages
Adding zope.interface 4.1.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\env\lib\site-packages\zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-win32.egg
Searching for repoze.lru>=0.4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/repoze.lru/
Best match: repoze.lru 0.6
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/repoze.lru/repoze.lru-0.6.tar.gz#md5=2c3b64b17a8e18b405f55d46173e14dd
Processing repoze.lru-0.6.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-sbw6vu\repoze.lru-0.6\setup.cfg
Running repoze.lru-0.6\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-sbw6vu\repoze.lru-0.6\egg-dist-tmp-o5ek4v
Adding repoze.lru 0.6 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\env\lib\site-packages\repoze.lru-0.6-py2.7.egg
Searching for WebOb>=1.3.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/WebOb/
Best match: WebOb 1.3.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/W/WebOb/WebOb-1.3.1.tar.gz#md5=20918251c5726956ba8fef22d1556177
Processing WebOb-1.3.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-8x1ebc\WebOb-1.3.1\setup.cfg
Running WebOb-1.3.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\tracy\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-8x1ebc\WebOb-1.3.1\egg-dist-tmp-dgnzem
no previously-included directories found matching '*.pyc'
no previously-included directories found matching '*.pyo'
Adding webob 1.3.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\env\lib\site-packages\webob-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for pyramid==1.5

C:\env>python pyramid_hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyramid_hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\config\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pyramid.interfaces import (
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5-py2.7.egg\pyramid\interfaces.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zope.deprecation import deprecated
ImportError: No module named deprecation

C:\env>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last command uses system-wide python in `C:\Python27` that is available using %PATH% variable.

Just change your last command to use

```
C:\env>.\Scripts\python pyramid_hello.py
```

or from any directory containing your scripts use an absolute path to run it with your %VENV% python interpreter.

```
c:\scripts>%VENV%\Scripts\python pyramid_hello.py
```

May be you will find it more convenient to activate/deactivate your virtualenv. Experienced users tend to have it explicit and the pyramid docs usually do not use virtualenv activation. For pyramid beginners it may be a good idea for their first steps. Just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the [installation instructions](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#installing-pyramid-on-a-windows-system).  The instructions should help you install everything you need to run "Hello World".

Comment: I did follow the instructions.

Comment: Steve is absolutely right. It is obvious from your commands that you do not use a virtualenv. Make sure you create a virtualenv, install pyramid into it, and start your python file with interpreter from that environment. Pay close attension when reading docs to commands with %VENV% environment variable.

Comment: The documentation also states that you don't have to use virtualenv. I tried it with virtualenv and I get the same error. See update above

Comment: The docs say to create a virtualenv and install Pyramid into it. It is optional to _activate_ the virtualenv. These are two totally different things, and the distinction is important. Activating a virtualenv is the equivalent of prepending the path to the executables in the virtualenv when you issue commands. Ultimately when issuing commands, you need to provide a proper path to the executable, whether that is by using the fully qualified path from your system root, relative to your current location, through the use of an environment variable %VENV%, or through `activate`.

Comment: Sascha's comment is also correct and provides two ways to use the python that is in your virtualenv, not the system-wide python as your commands were using.  Sascha's first example uses a relative path whereas the second uses a (hopefully correctly set) `%VENV%` environment variable, both of which should resolve to the python in your virtualenv.